# VB.NET : Populating Gridview with Dates (30 days interval)

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I am trying to populate a gridview with dates.

For example the date today is 2/18/2019 and the next date within 30 days is 3/20/2019. so the desired output shoul'd look like this

```
No.     Date
1       3/20/2019
2       4/19/2019
3       5/19/2019
```

etc.

but the result is

```
No.     Date
1       3/20/2019
2       3/20/2019
3       3/20/2019
```

etc.

Here is my code so far.

```
Dim termCounter As Integer = 36
Dim today As DateTime = DateTime.Today
Dim dueDate As DateTime = today.AddDays(30)

Dim dtable As DataTable = New DataTable()
dtable.Columns.Add("No.")
dtable.Columns.Add("Payment Date")
Dim RowValues As Object() = {"", ""}
Dim dRow As DataRow

Dim tmpDate As Date
For i As Integer = 1 To termCounter
                    If GridAmortSched.RowCount <= 0 Then
                        RowValues(0) = i
                        RowValues(1) = dueDate.ToShortDateString
                        dRow = dtable.Rows.Add(RowValues)
                    Else
                        tmpDate = GridAmortSched.Rows(GridAmortSched.RowCount - 1).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
                        RowValues(0) = i
                        RowValues(1) = tmpDate.AddDays(30).ToShortDateString
                        dRow = dtable.Rows.Add(RowValues)
                    End If
                Next
                dtable.AcceptChanges()
                GridAmortSched.DataSource = dtable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is often the case, the code is behaving as you have told it to do, not at you want it to do :-).

Every time you go through the loop, you set `tmpDate` from the same source and then two lines later, you put the value into `RowValues`. :

```
tmpDate = GridAmortSched.Rows(GridAmortSched.RowCount - 1).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
```

You do not adjust your source by `i`, nor do you increment it. When you `AddDays`, you do not adjust the original value either (which would not work because of how and when you assign it).

### Two easy fixes (two options)

**One.** The first is to index the days to be added against the loop value - the simple modification to the code below will achieve this. It is a quick fix and may be harder to maintain in the future - more to the point, is harder to spot if you change something such as the loop starting point.

```
RowValues(1) = tmpDate.AddDays(30*i).ToShortDateString
```

**Two.** The other option is to address the code logic. Set your baseline value and then increment it within the loop.

```
Dim tmpDate As Date
tmpDate = GridAmortSched.Rows(GridAmortSched.RowCount - 1).Cells(1).Value.ToString() '*** Moved outside of loop
For i As Integer = 1 To termCounter
    If GridAmortSched.RowCount <= 0 Then
        RowValues(0) = i
        RowValues(1) = dueDate.ToShortDateString
        dRow = dtable.Rows.Add(RowValues)
    Else

        RowValues(0) = i
        tmpDate = tmpDate.AddDays(30) '*** Increment date every time it passes here
        RowValues(1) = tmpDate.ToShortDateString '*** Assign the new value
        dRow = dtable.Rows.Add(RowValues)
    End If
Next
dtable.AcceptChanges()
GridAmortSched.DataSource = dtable
```

Comment: Works Perfectly, thanks. I will keep in mind all of your comments.